# About mybatis3.3 databaseId,the code is useless

Tags: mybatis

I study the mybatis3.3 sources code and now I have a question：in the XMLMapperBuilder.databaseIdMatchesCurrent()

```
private boolean databaseIdMatchesCurrent(String id, String databaseId, String requiredDatabaseId) {
    if (requiredDatabaseId != null) {
      if (!requiredDatabaseId.equals(databaseId)) {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      if (databaseId != null) {
        return false;
      }
      // skip this fragment if there is a previous one with a not null databaseId
      if (this.sqlFragments.containsKey(id)) {
        XNode context = this.sqlFragments.get(id);
        if (context.getStringAttribute("databaseId") != null) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

if the (requiredDatabaseId == null && databaseId != null) ,then the function will return false.
So the code

```
 if (this.sqlFragments.containsKey(id)) {
            XNode context = this.sqlFragments.get(id);
            if (context.getStringAttribute("databaseId") != null) {
              return false;
            }
          }
```

certainly no way to return false and this code is useless.
I just want to questioning: I understand this, right?

Comment: If I understand, you are saying that the last code block can't return false. But If (requireDatabaseId == null && databaseId == null), and the two "if conditions" of the last code block are true, it returns false, otherwise the last line will be executed (return true). Do I understand well?

Comment: `if (databaseId != null) {
        return false;
      }`

Comment: And so? If databaseId equals null, it can return either false or true based on the other two if conditions.